# Mean time that lapsed between records

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a table of car ids  - `id` and their battery level - `battery`, which are collected at ten-minute intervals.

My goal is the following output: the average time that it takes for batteries to drop from 100 to 0.  My objective is to take the global mean across all car ids, that is, the mean time difference between where `battery = 100` and `battery = 0` for all unique ids.  One small caveat is that the 0 *must come after* the 100, in other words, I would like to exclude charging times (when 100 would come after a 0).

How would one write such a query in `psql` ?

Here is a sample of the data of one car :

```
  id|                           time| battery
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:50:04.402775+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:40:04.618926+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:30:04.11399+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:20:03.906716+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:10:03.955133+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:00:04.678508+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:50:03.733471+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:40:03.65688+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:30:04.260608+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:20:03.98387+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:10:04.164129+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:00:04.597976+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:50:04.501231+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:40:04.441531+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:30:04.310876+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:20:04.317241+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:10:03.856432+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:00:03.628862+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:50:03.868495+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:40:04.490324+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:30:03.83739+00  |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:20:03.817014+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:10:04.081174+00 |      29
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:00:04.178765+00 |      29





    data_type         
--------------------------
 integer
 timestamp with time zone
 integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you only want the 100s that have a 0 before the next 100.

```
select avg(extract(epoch from (next_time - time) ) as avg_recharge_time
from (select t.*,
             lead(battery) over (partition by id order by time) as next_battery,
             lead(time) over (partition by id order by time) as next_time
      from t
      where battery in (0, 100)
     ) t
where battery = 100 and next_battery = 0;
```

This answers the question that you have asked.  However. I can imagine that your situation is more complicated.  For instance, if batteries can be partially recharged, then this will give incorrect results.  If you have situations like that, ask *another* question, with suitable sample data and explanations.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Thanks for noting that.  It is possible to partially recharge and therefore all cases where there is an increase in charge should be excluded.  I will start a new thread